# HTML <form> input blocked after WASM loads

Tags: html, c, forms, web, webassembly

Please could somebody help me to resolve this problem?
I have canvas, inserted in html and drawn usng WebAssembly in C, however it seems to block the HTML form input fields - I cannot type anything once the wasm module is loaded and runs...

**I use emscripten_set_main_loop_arg() in C instead, of requestAnimationFrame() in JS:**

```
const int simulate_infinite_loop = 1; // call the function repeatedly
const int fps = -1; // call the function as fast as the browser wants to render (typically 60fps)
emscripten_set_main_loop_arg(render, &cbp, fps, simulate_infinite_loop);
```

Later, I insert it in HTML:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var Module = {};
    fetch('app/aghdr.wasm')
    .then(response =>
        response.arrayBuffer()
    ).then(buffer => {
        Module.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        Module.wasmBinary = buffer;
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "app/aghdr.js";
        script.onload = function() {
        console.log("Emscripten boilerplate loaded.")
        }
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    });
</script>
```

**Does anybody know, hot to ensure that normal *HTML form* processes messages while WASM module is running?**

See: http://inters.cloud/test3/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's caused by `emscripten_set_keypress_callback()`.
When a argument callback returns non-zero, `event.preventDefault()` blocks a keypress event.

Comment: Thanks @zakki,
I just resolved this by adding:
`code`
 emscripten_set_keypress_callback(0, 0, 0, 0);
 emscripten_set_keydown_callback(0, 0, 0, 0);
 emscripten_set_keyup_callback(0, 0, 0, 0);
`code`

Comment: @zakki could you please explain how to solve that without removing the event listeners in C++?

Comment: Is it possible to `return 0;` in a callback  function or set a approprivate first parameter of `emscripten_set_keypress_callback`? Maybe it depends on the situation.